# Вывод на сайте информации из модели без for

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Задача проста, но ничего не выходит. Есть модель, содержащая переменную. Мне необходимо вывести на сайте информацию из этой переменной, при чём не используя for. Через админку добавил в эту переменную пару значений. Вывести нужно отдельно первое и второе значения.

*foods\models.py*

```
from django.db import models


class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

В foods\views.py сейчас ничего не написано. Требуется вывести информацию из переменной name

*orders\models.py*

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

from foods.models import Food


class PizzaOrder(models.Model):
    cost = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    food = models.ManyToManyField(Food)

class Preference(models.Model):
    preferences = models.TextField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.preferences
```

*orders\views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from project.forms import PreferenceForm


def main_page(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def foods_page(request):
    form = PreferenceForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        form = PreferenceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, '2index.html', context)
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from orders.views import main_page, foods_page

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', main_page),
    path('foods/', foods_page),
]
```

*forms.py*

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from orders.models import Preference


class PreferenceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Preference
        fields = ('preferences',)
```

*2index.html (шаблон для второй страницы сайта)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Foods page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-info">
        <div class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">PT</div>
        <strong>PizzaTown</strong>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
                aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="home/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="foods/">Foods</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="orders/">Orders</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: azure">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="https://api.papajohns.by//images/catalog/thumbs/full/01879ec69cd11aab78a56670ad6d6b52.png"
                         class="card-img-top" alt="Error">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="https://api.papajohns.by//images/catalog/thumbs/full/fe239676da6c27d17d5e64b81f23a1e0.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top" alt="Error">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="https://api.papajohns.by//images/catalog/thumbs/full/20ebe40c3cd391721de15e2df703f83b.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top" alt="Error">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="https://api.papajohns.by//images/catalog/thumbs/full/e89e7886255685e4de87fea5ec5bbd60.png"
                         class="card-img-top" alt="Error">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="https://api.papajohns.by//images/catalog/thumbs/full/92abaa6fbf6240f53f9ecff2e4813709.png"
                         class="card-img-top" alt="Error">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="https://api.papajohns.by//images/catalog/thumbs/full/e6e96cb5447c26324b317b5cd5144e97.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top" alt="Error">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="https://api.papajohns.by//images/catalog/thumbs/full/03993f82fb00da9721e741202854a43e.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top" alt="Error">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="https://api.papajohns.by//images/catalog/thumbs/full/589efbfc513ff9a069e4790c2bbcbdf9.png"
                         class="card-img-top" alt="Error">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="https://api.papajohns.by//images/catalog/thumbs/full/71b9b358e834a863bc3906474601a967.png"
                         class="card-img-top" alt="Error">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Напишите представление, которое передаст в шаблон конкретный экземпляр модели. В шаблоне выведите через `{{ obj.name }}`. В чём проблемы?

Comment: @nomnoms12 `from django.shortcuts import render


from foods.models import Food


def foods_page(request):


    a = Food()


    return render(request, '2index.html', info = {"food": a})`

Comment: Что Вы хотите сделать кодом, который сейчас привели? Во-первых, Вы создаёте новый экземпляр `Food` (который не сохраняете). А во-вторых, у функции `render` нет параметра `info` (Вам нужен `context`).

Comment: Получить экземпляры модели можно через `Food.objects` ([`objects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/class/#django.db.models.Model.objects)). См. также [Making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#making-queries).

Comment: @nomnoms12 тогда как мне подключить модель?

Comment: @nomnoms12 ведь там задаётся конкретное значение, а мне нужно вывести уже имеющиеся

Comment: Вы можете получить все экземпляры конкретной модели через `Food.objects.all()`. Но как их вывести без цикла `for` в общем случае, я не представляю. Можно уточнить, экземпляров будет фиксированное количество или разное?

Comment: @nomnoms12 их всегда будет 9

Comment: Тогда можете руками передавать их по-одному в контекст: `{'food_1': Food.objects.all()[0]}` и т. д. Но это довольно неудобно. Почему бы Вам не использовать `for`?

Comment: @nomnoms12 я хочу вывести названия внутри 9 карточек, которые имеют разные картинки. Если я правильно понимаю, то с использованием for мне придётся запихнуть туда и создание карточки

Comment: Похоже, Что Это [Проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/339283). Пожалуйста, приведите больше информации о Вашем проекте, а именно о _"карточках"_ и _"картинках"_. Я думаю, что отказ от цикла `for` не является приемлемым решением и Вашу задачу можно решить иначе (возможно, на уровне моделей). Добавить информацию в вопрос Вы можете, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: @nomnoms12 добавил всё, кроме первого шаблона, с ним всё (почти) в порядке.  Ваш совет я опробовал, не вышло, может что-то опять не так сделал...

Comment: @nomnoms12 всё, я понял как вывести методом, который вы указали выше. Да, не через for, но зато выводятся значения из модели, этого хватит для доклада. Останется только разобраться в кнопках, спасибо! )